# Convert size in bytes to unsigned integral type

Tags: c++, types, c++20

I am developing a library that needs to auto deduce the type of size (in bytes).

How to convert size (in bytes) to unsigned integral type?

The type deduced must be big enough to store data in the size, but that does not mean to use `uint64_t` in every case.

C++20 or below can be used.

To be clearer, I want to deduce a type to store data of the size but without memory waste.

For example:

```cpp
magic<1> -> uint8_t
magic<2> -> uint16_t
magic<3> -> uint32_t
magic<7> -> uint64_t
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean to me. Isn't ```size_t``` the type you need? Or do you have a fixed size and want to know how big your int has to be for it?

Comment: This is not a difficult problem, a simple `conditional_t` should be enough, that is, choose whether to use `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, etc. according to the value of size.

Comment: @JonathanS. I want to deduce a type to store   data of the size   but without memory waste.

Comment: Types do not have unique size. For example, all integral types _may_ have the same size. I do not understand. `How to convert size (in bytes) to unsigned integral type?` Could you give an example? It looks simple - create an array of pairs size and type, search the array for the size and return the types.

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated the question. It should look better.

Comment: Why don't you just use a ```char[]```? What "data" do you want to store, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately invoked lambda might help. You can also use `std::conditional_t`.

```
template<std::size_t N>
using magic = decltype([] {
  if constexpr (N <= 1)
    return std::uint8_t{};
  else if constexpr (N <= 2)
    return std::uint16_t{};
  else if constexpr (N <= 4)
    return std::uint32_t{};
  else {  
    static_assert(N <= 8);
    return std::uint64_t{};
  }
}());
```

Comment: It seems not cross-platform. Replace 1,2,4,8 to sizeof.

Comment: @Creepercdn Portability in this case is matter of requirements (of which you gave none). Hardcoded values for `magic` are only non-portable if you need to support a system where `CHAR_BIT != 8`. A bigger problem would be that neither of `std::uint*_t` types are required by standard, so if you want to port to a system that doesn't provide them, complexity of the templates may blow up.